# How to create a composite variable from survey data?

Tags: r, predictive-models, survey, composite

I'm working with survey data, which I've never done before (from the SHARE database). What I basically want to do is create a composite variable for cognitive function, mental health and maybe some others from variables where some are objective measures (numeracy, memory etc.) and some are self-rated or rated by a close one on a likert scale. I want to do this because I'd like to be able to run a prediction on cognitive health. Is this viable and if so, how would I go about doing it?Any help is appreciated.
P.S. I'm doing the analysis in R.

Comment: Is it really meaningful to combine measures of depression and cognition?

Comment: They wouldn't be combined, there would be two separate variables for them.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a common approach in your field? I mean forming composites over several self-report measures *and* performance-based measures such as cognitive tests? Not that there's necessarily anything inherently wrong with it but by my reading it seems uncommon and may make it more difficult to publish your results (if your goal is journal publication). Usually you'd make separate composites of pre-established scales or maybe combined some scales with very similar content. Also, it could be argued that self-reports and reports by close other offer slightly different perspective, so averaging them loses information.

However, to do this, a typical way to start would be factor analysis. As you have the idea that all these scales and tests could be combined, you could test a one-factor confirmatory factor analysis. In essence, you'd try to find evidence that your different measures are indeed all strongly related to each other, strongly enough that they can be said to be represented by one common latent factor. lavaan is a great package for CFA in R. If you want to try exploratory factor analysis (in which the model will suggest number of factors to you), package psych has good functions.

Then again, because you're particularly interested in prediction,  maybe another way would be some type of penalized regression such as LASSO or elastic net regression. For this, you don't need to form a composite but you can put all your predictors into the model to get the best predictive model (I don't know much about this approach, just a thought).